# (Flutter) AdMob Test Mode doesn't show

Tags: android, flutter, dart, admob, emulation

I'm a beginner who just studied Flutter.

I wanted to use the admob package to put a small banner ad in my emulator. I wrote the source code using the tutorial and several example codes. The problem is, no matter how you do it, I can't see the test ad.

Here I attach my source code. As you can see, there's no other function because it is a code created to see the ad appear well in the first place. There is only one ad code in body and one text code in bottom. I don't know why such an error message appears. I searched lots of  communities and stackoverflow starting with Google. It only deals with error statements that occur when using actual devices in release mode. My Error happned at the emulator, in debugging mode.

I can't continue for two weeks because of this Error. Even a small piece of advice would be of great help. Help me pls.

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';


void main(){
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();  // 모바일 광고 SDK 초기화

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: HomeScreen(),
  ));
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-################/##########',
      size: AdSize.banner,
      request: AdRequest(),
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        // Called when an ad is successfully received.
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) => debugPrint('Ad loaded.'),
        // Called when an ad request failed.
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
        // Dispose the ad here to free resources.
        ad.dispose();
        debugPrint('Ad failed to load ㅅㅂ: $error');
        },
        // Called when an ad opens an overlay that covers the screen.
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => debugPrint('Ad opened.'),
        // Called when an ad removes an overlay that covers the screen.
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => debugPrint('Ad closed.'),
        // Called when an impression occurs on the ad.
        onAdImpression: (Ad ad) => debugPrint('Ad impression.'),
      )
    )..load();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("AdMob Tutorial"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: AdWidget(ad: myBanner,),
        width: myBanner.size.width.toDouble(),
        height: myBanner.size.height.toDouble(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Text("될까..?"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuJCU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please use ad manager test id
https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/test-ads